# Adding RecordID in front of copied file

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a code that copies a file from one location to another. What I would like it that when the file is copied, the recordID is placed in front of the file name (example: 150-FirstName). Here is the code I'm working with:

```
Private Sub cmd_LocateFile_Click()
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
Dim sFile                 As String
Dim sFolder               As String

sFile = FSBrowse("", msoFileDialogFilePicker, "All Files (*.*),*.*")
If sFile <> "" Then
    sFolder = Application.CodeProject.path & "\" & sAttachmentFolderName & "\"
    If FolderExist(sFolder) = False Then MkDir (sFolder)
    If CopyFile(sFile, sFolder & GetFileName(sFile)) = True Then
        Me.FullFileName = sFolder & GetFileName(sFile)
    Else
    End If
End If

Error_Handler_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Source: " & sModName & "\cmd_LocateFile_Click" & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
       Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
       , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
Dim Id As Long
Dim sTarget As String

Id = YourRecordID  ' Set current record id.
sTarget = sFolder & CStr(Id) & "-" & GetFileName(sFile)

' Replace your current If-Then-Else-End If block.
If CopyFile(sFile, sTarget)) = True Then
    Me!FullFileName.Value = sTarget
End If
```

Comment: Could you give a full sample of where to put this code? I've tried and I keep getting  errors.  Thanks

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help.